# Could not locate the element please fine below code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am not able to locate the element here is my code and attachment of resources.

I found the exception NoSuchElement found please help me out. I am trying drag and drop functionality .

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\TopsAssignment\\SampleJavaExample\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/draggable/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#draggable")));


    WebElement dragElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#draggable"));

    Actions acs = new Actions(driver);

    Action act = acs.dragAndDropBy(dragElement, 200, 500).build();

    act.perform();

    driver.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine with below code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\TopsAssignment\\SampleJavaExample\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/droppable/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.switchTo().frame(0);


    WebElement dragElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#draggable"));
    WebElement dropable = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable"));

    Actions acs = new Actions(driver);

    Action act = acs.dragAndDrop(dragElement,dropable).build();

    act.perform();

    driver.close();



}
```